# MySql Remote accessing in php

Tags: mysql

I want to connect mysql database remotely in detail i want to make application like this my database is only in hosted server and my php pages are always offline means in client pc. it is possible or not. if yes then how it possible. i am using godaddy hosting server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but here are some limitations:

- Client PC has an internet service (Static IP is preferred)
- Remote access service is only available on paid hosting plans
- Connection do not support secured connections (SSL)

Steps:

1. Log in to your Account Manager.
2. Click **Web Hosting**.
3. Next to the cPanel account you want to use, click **Launch**.
4. In the **Databases** section, click **Remote MySQL**.
5. In the **Host** field, enter the IP address (Your Client PC IP).
6. Click **Add Host**.

Reference:

- [Enabling Remote MySQL Management in cPanel](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/8832/enabling-remote-mysql-management-in-cpanel?locale=en)
- [Why connect remotely to hosting databases?](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4977/why-connect-remotely-to-hosting-databases?locale=en)
- [Connecting Remotely to Shared Hosting Databases](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4978/connecting-remotely-to-shared-hosting-databases?locale=en)